# How can RTT Viewer show print data in e2Studio for EK-RA6m4 kit of renesas?

Tags: segger-jlink

using EK-R`A6M4, running sample code of FreeRTOS_Lab1, RTT viewer is getting connected over USB, but do not show any data.

I right clicked on project and clicked on 'Debug As'. selected option of 'Renesas GDB hardware debugger". Other options do not work.

tried to debug below function, but could not get to the root of problem

```
  SEGGER_RTT_printf(0, "%s %lu\r\n", string, value);
```

Jlink RTT Viewer ver 7.88 and 7.94 are tried. e2Studio version is Version: 2023-10 (23.10.0)

How to make rttviewer working? or else what are the other options to display print strings during debug?

I right cl`icked on project and clicked on 'Debug As'. selected option of 'Renesas GDB hardware debugger". Other options do not work.

tried to debug below function, but could not get to the root of problem

```
  SEGGER_RTT_printf(0, "%s %lu\r\n", string, value)
```

I am using` Jlink RTT Viewer ver 7.88 and 7.94 are tried. e2Studio version is Version: 2023-10 (23.10.0)
GNU Arm tools are used

How to make rttviewer working? or else what are the other options to display print strings during debug?